# Describing how a contained object/subject limits the minimum size of its container

Tags: single-word-requests

If A is inside B, it might be said that the size of B constricts the maximum size of A. What is the word to describe A's limiting effect on the minimum size of B? What I'm trying to describe is how an increase in size of A affects B.

For added bonus, a better word than 'constricts' is also useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can say that A ***forces*** B to be a minimum size; or that A ***limits*** the minimum size of B.

Or possibly that A ***constrains*** B **to be larger** (that is, it puts a constraint on the size such that it cannot fall below a particular value).

Comment: +1 for *constrain*. It's what I was going to answer with, anyway.